# Data Type GETDATE does not match a Defined Type name

Tags: sql, teradata

Executing this statement in Teradata `SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE(),  -2) AS month_calculated` outputs

> Data Type GETDATE does not match a Defined Type name

What is wrong with this syntax?

Comment: DATE in Teradata will get the current date, Instead of GETDATE() try using DATE

Comment: This syntax is supported by MS SQL Server. Not sure about Teradata

Comment: @Vinoth.R I tried ```SELECT EOMONTH(DATE,  -2) AS month_calculated```. The output is now ```cannot resolve column EOMONTH```. Specify table or view.

Comment: The syntax that you are using is for SQL server, Which may not work with teradata

Comment: @bibscy Try this  :   SELECT ADD_MONTHS (DATE , -2);

Comment: @bibscy Cool will post the same as answer, will be useful for someone

Comment: Well, to get the same output you need nested functions: `last_day(add_months(current_date, -2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above syntax is for the SQL server, For teradata we have to use

```
 SELECT ADD_MONTHS (DATE , -2);
```

- DATE in Teradata will get the current date
- ADD_MONTHS lets you add or subtract a number of months